# Issue with updating view inside WindowManager in Android

Tags: android, layout, view, android-windowmanager

Here is the code for adding WindowManager to stay on top of other views.

```
private View mainView;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE);
       params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
               PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
params.x = 0;
params.y = 0;
windowManager.addView(mainView, params);
```

It works fine. Inflating a layout inside the window manager and updating the layout dynamically. But I am unable to update the view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(CallTimerService.this);
       mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call_dialog, null);
callerNameTv = (TextView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.caller_name);
callerNameTv.setText(name);
```

setText method is called and there is no exception but the view is not updated. Can anyone point out the issue here?

Comment: It looks to me like you're inflating a new hierarchy in which you find and update `R.id.caller_name`. Unless you're attaching that newly inflated view hierarchy (with updated view) somewhere else, it will never be visible.

Comment: No need to inflate `mainView` again just use the same `mainView` which you have added to `windowManager`.

Comment: The problem is with the SYSTEM_OVERLAY. If the type is something else, all is well.

Answer (score 1):

Update the specific view you wish to modify:

```java
    // Get the view params
    WindowManager.LayoutParams paramNameTV = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) callerNameTv .getLayoutParams(); 
    //update the view layout
    windowManager.updateViewLayout(callerNameTv, paramNameTV);
```